# How to keep wesbite within subdomain and prevent redirect to root folder

Tags: apache

I have a website in my root folder and within that have a subfolder with another test site. The issue is that the test site in the subfolder seems to be pulling in the content from the root folder.

I'm assuming I need an .htaccess in my subfolder as well but I don't know how to prevent it from redirecting (if that is in fact what's happening). I've tried a whole bunch of differnet solutions I've found on the web but I don't actually understand exactly what needs to be written.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Not sure I'm following you Dhaman. It's about accessing a website in my subfolder hosted on a server

Comment: I thought the issue might have to do with something on the server / phpmyadmin

Answer (score 0):

To anyone who has the same issue - who has a website in a subfolder and is dealing with redirect issues to the root folder here is how I solved it:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /subfolder/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /subfolder/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```